# How can I build HTML with a Makefile with backlinks?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to statically build HTML files that requires a markdown file and a meta file called "whatlinkshere" for the HTML file to demonstrate its [back links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink).

I believe it can be effeciently done by a Makefile, by first generating all the "whatlinkshere" files. I don't think this can be done in parallel, because the program that generates these files needs to append to the whatlinkshere files, and there could be race conditions that I am not quite sure how to solve.

Once the "whatlinkshere" files are generated then if a markdown file is edited, say *foo.mdwn to point to bar.mdwn*, only foo.mdwn needs to be analysed again for "whatlinkshere" changes. And finally only foo.html and bar.html need to be rebuilt.

I am struggling to accomplish this in my [backlinks project](https://github.com/kaihendry/backlinks).

```
INFILES = $(shell find . -name "*.mdwn")
OUTFILES = $(INFILES:.mdwn=.html)
LINKFILES = $(INFILES:.mdwn=.whatlinkshere)

all: $(OUTFILES)

# These need to be all made before the HTML is processed
$(LINKFILES): $(INFILES)
    @echo Creating backlinks $@
    @touch $@
    @go run backlinks.go $<

%.html: %.mdwn %.whatlinkshere
    @echo Deps $^
    @cmark $^ > $@
```

Current problems here is that *.whatlinkshere** aren't being generated on first run. My workaround is `for i in *.mdwn; do go run backlinks.go $i; done`. Furthermore there are not rebuilding as I want after editing a file as described earlier. Something is horribly wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: Your first rule looks strange to me. It tells make that each `foo.whatlinkshere` in the `$(LINKFILES)` list depends on **all** `mdwn` files in the `$(INFILES)` list but it uses only the **first** one (the `$<` automatic variable expands as the first prerequisite) to build them. And I do not understand the `touch` command. If the `go...` command is supposed to generate the target, what is its purpose? Finally, you explain that if `foo.mdwn` changes, `foo.mdwn` and `bar.mdwn` must be rebuilt. Do you mean that your source files (`*.mdwn`) are also targets? They depend on themselves?

Comment: touch is to make sure there is a "whatlinkshere" file even if nothing links there, to ensure the build html target doesn't error if the file isn't there. I want `go run backlinks.go` to run on every .mdwn file (instead of the last file), but I am not sure how to express that.

Comment: I will answer your question but first, what about the other question: do you mean that your source files (`*.mdwn`) are also targets? They depend on themselves?

Comment: *.mdwn are not targets. But I made an update to https://github.com/kaihendry/backlinks though I still could do with your help Renaud. Thank you.

Comment: Then, I really don't understand. You write (copy-paste): "_Once the "whatlinkshere" files are generated then if a markdown file is edited, say foo.mdwn to point to bar.mdwn, only foo.mdwn needs to be analysed again for "whatlinkshere" changes. And finally only foo.mdwn and bar.mdwn need to be rebuilt_". I insist: **foo.mdwn and bar.mdwn need to be rebuilt**. I don't understand this, can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, foo.mdwn need to be rebuilt to show the new link, bar.mdwn needs to be rebuilt with bar.whatlinkshere to show the back link. I have perhaps a clearer explanation on the README.md https://github.com/kaihendry/backlinks#other-issue Apologies for my lack of clarity.

Comment: Sorry but I give up, I initially thought that  you wanted to generate HTML files from Mardown files but it appears that you want to generate Markdown files from Mardown files (themselves) and I do not understand how all this is supposed to work. I hope somebody else will understand and be able to help.

Comment: In `go run backlinks.go...` line, try using `$^` instead of `$<`. See docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html.  BTW, for debugging purposes, try to remove `@` from beginning of recipe commands. You will see what is executed, and if that is expected.

Comment: An idea came to my mind: when you write "_**bar.mdwn** needs to be **rebuilt**_" do you mean that it must be re-analyzed or do you mean that it must be re-generated?

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be analysed. It's not a target. Markdown can always be considered a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally understood your problem. If I understood well:

1. You have a bunch of `*.mdwn` source files.
2. You generate `*.whatlinkshere` files from your `*.mdwn` source files using the `backlinks.go` utility. But this utility does not produce `foo.whatlinkshere` from `foo.mdwn`. It analyzes `foo.mdwn`, searches for links to other pages in it and, for each link to `bar` it finds, it **appends** a `[foo](foo.html)` reference to `bar.whatlinkshere`.
3. From each `foo.mdwn` source file you want to build a corresponding `foo.html` file with:

   ```
   $ cmark foo.mdwn foo.whatlinkshere
   ```

Your rule:

```
$(LINKFILES): $(INFILES)
    @echo Creating backlinks $@
    @touch $@
    @go run backlinks.go $<
```

contains one error and has several drawbacks. The error is the use of the `$<` automatic variable in the recipe. It expands as the first prerequisite, that is probably always `pageA.mdwn` in your case. Not what you want. `$^` expands as all prerequisites but it is not the correct solution because:

1. your go utility takes only one source file name, but even if it was accepting several...
2. ...make will run the recipe several times, one per link file, which is a waste, and...
3. ...as your go utility appends to the link files it will even be worse than a waste: back links will be counted several times each, and...
4. ...if make runs in parallel mode (note that you can prevent this with `make -j1` or by adding the `.NOTPARALLEL:` special rule to your Makefile, but it is a pity) there is a risk of race conditions.

**Important**: the following works only with a flat organization where all source files and HTML files are in the same directory as the Makefile. Other organizations are possible, of course, but they would require some modifications.

#### First option using multi-targets pattern rules

One possibility is to use a special property of make pattern rules: when they have several targets make considers that one single execution of the recipe produces all targets. For instance:

```
pageA.w%e pageB.w%e pageC.w%e: pageA.mdwn pageB.mdwn pageC.mdwn
    for m in $^; do go run backlinks.go $$m; done
```

tells make that `pageA.whatlinkshere`, `pageB.whatlinkshere` and `pageC.whatlinkshere` are all generated by one execution of:

```
for m in pageA.mdwn pageB.mdwn pageC.mdwn; do go run backlinks.go $m; done
```

(make expands `$^` as all prerequisites and `$$m` as `$m`). Of course, we want to automate the computation of the `pageA.w%e pageB.w%e pageC.w%e` pattern targets list. This should make it:

```
INFILES     := $(shell find . -name "*.mdwn")
OUTFILES    := $(INFILES:.mdwn=.html)
LINKFILES   := $(INFILES:.mdwn=.whatlinkshere)
LINKPATTERN := $(INFILES:.mdwn=.w%e)

.PHONY: all clean
.PRECIOUS: $(LINKFILES)

all: $(OUTFILES)

# These need to be all made before the HTML is processed
$(LINKPATTERN): $(INFILES)
    @echo Creating backlinks
    @rm -f $(LINKFILES)
    @touch $(LINKFILES)
    @for m in $^; do go run backlinks.go $$m; done

%.html: %.mdwn %.whatlinkshere
    @echo Deps $^
    @cmark $^ > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(LINKFILES) $(OUTFILES)
```

Notes:

- I declared `all` and `clean` as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) because... it is what they are.
- I declared the `whatlinkshere` files as [precious](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002ePRECIOUS-intermediate-files) because (some of them) are considered by make as intermediates and without this declaration make would delete them after building the HTML files.
- In the recipe for the `whatlinkshere` files I added `rm -f $(LINKFILES)` such that, if the recipe is executed, we restart from a clean state instead of concatenating new stuff to old (possibly outdated) references.
- The pattern stem in the `$(LINKPATTERN)` can be anything but must match at least one character. I used `w%e` but `whatlin%shere` would work too. Use whatever is specific enough in your case. If you have a `pageB.where` file prefer `whatlin%shere` or `what%here`.

There is a drawback with this solution but it is due to your particular set-up: each time one single `mdwn` file changes it must be re-analyzed (which is normal) but any `whatlinkshere` file can be impacted. This is not predictable, it depends on the links that have been modified in this source file. But more problematic is the fact that the result of this analysis is **appended** to the impacted `whatlinkshere` files. They are not "*edited*" with the old content relative to this source file replaced by the new one. So, if you change just a comment in a source file, all its links will be appended again to the respective `whatlinkshere` files (while they are already there). This is probably not what you want.

This is why the solution above deletes all `whatlinkshere` files and re-analyzes all source files each time one single source file changes. And another negative consequence is that all HTML files must also be re-generated because all `whatlinkshere` files changed (even if their content did not really change, but make does not know this). If the analysis is super fast and you have a small number of `mdwn` files, it should be OK. Else it is sub-optimal but not easy to solve because of your particular set-up.

#### Second option using recursive make, separated back link files and marker files

There is a possibility, however, which consists in:

1. separating all back links references with one `whatlinkshere` file per from/to pair: `foo.backlinks/bar.whatlinkshere` contains all references to `bar` found in `foo.mdwn`,
2. using recursive make with one first invocation (when the `STEP` make variable is unset) to update all `whatlinkshere` files that need to be and a second invocation (`STEP` set to 2) to generate the HTML files that need to be,
3. using empty dummy files to mark that a `foo.mdwn` file has been analyzed: `foo.backlinks/.done`,
4. using the [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) to be able to refer to the stem of a pattern rule in its list of prerequisites (and using `$$` to escape the fist expansion).

But it is probably a bit more difficult to understand (and maintain).

```
INFILES   := $(shell find . -name "*.mdwn")
OUTFILES  := $(INFILES:.mdwn=.html)
DONEFILES := $(patsubst %.mdwn,%.backlinks/.done,$(INFILES))

.PHONY: all clean

ifeq ($(STEP),)
all $(OUTFILES): $(DONEFILES)
    $(MAKE) STEP=2 $@

%.backlinks/.done: %.mdwn
    rm -rf $(dir $@)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp $< $(dir $@)
    cd $(dir $@); go run ../backlinks.go $<; rm $<
    touch $@
else
all: $(OUTFILES)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.html: %.mdwn $$(wildcard *.backlinks/$$*.whatlinkshere)
    @echo Deps $^
    @cmark $^ > $@
endif

clean:
    rm -rf *.backlinks $(OUTFILES)
```

Even if it looks more complicated there are a few advantages with this version:

1. only outdated targets are rebuilt and only once each,
2. all `whatlinkshere` files are updated (if needed) before any HTML file is updated (if needed),
3. the `whatlinkshere` files can be built in parallel,
4. the HTML files can be built in parallel.

#### Third option using only recursive make and marker files

If you do not care about inaccurate results where back links persist in the results after they disappeared from the source files or where back links are uselessly replicated, we can reuse ideas from the previous solution but drop the separation in individual from/to `whatlinkshere` files.

```
INFILES     := $(wildcard *.mdwn)
OUTFILES    := $(patsubst %.mdwn,%.html,$(INFILES))
LINKFILES   := $(patsubst %.mdwn,%.whatlinkshere,$(INFILES))
DONEFILES   := $(patsubst %.mdwn,.%.done,$(INFILES))

.PHONY: all clean
.PRECIOUS: $(LINKFILES)

ifeq ($(STEP),)
.NOTPARALLEL:

all $(OUTFILES): $(DONEFILES)
    $(MAKE) STEP=2 $@

.%.done: %.mdwn
    go run backlinks.go $<
    touch $@
else
all: $(OUTFILES)

%.html: %.mdwn %.whatlinkshere
    @echo Deps $^
    @cmark $^ > $@

%.whatlinkshere:
    touch $@
endif

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTFILES) $(LINKFILES) $(DONEFILES)
```

Notes:

1. As this works only for a flat organization I replaced the `$(shell find...)` by the make built-in `$(wildcard ...)`.
2. I used `patsubst` instead of the old syntax but it's just a matter of taste.
3. The `%.whatlinkshere:` rule is a default rule to create the missing empty `whatlinkshere` files.
4. The `NOTPARALLEL:` special target prevents parallel execution when building the `whatlinkshere` files.

Comment: Just quickly trying it before leaving on a flight. First example: https://s.natalian.org/2018-12-19/53800273-1.mp4 Second proposal: https://s.natalian.org/2018-12-19/53800273-2.mp4
I'll ready your text closely when I get a chance. Thank you!

Comment: When copy-pasting, did you replace the leading spaces by tabs in the recipes?

Comment: Yes, I use vim to format the Makefiles spaces to tabs

Comment: About your test of the first solution: in your `README.md` you explain that, when modifying `pageC.mdwn` to add a link to `pageB`, you expect only `pageC.html`, `pageB.whatlinkshere` and `pageB.html` to be re-generated. But due to your setup it is not possible with this first "_simple_" version. As any `mdwn` file change can cause a change to any `whatlinkshere` and as your go utility appends to (not replace) the `whatlinkshere` files, there is no other possibility than re-analysing all source files. For a lighter update we need the separation introduced by the second version.

Comment: And with the second version, your editor indented too many lines: the `all $(OUTFILES): $(DONEFILES)` line shall not be indented. Same with the `all: $(OUTFILES)` line.

Comment: I append to .whatlinkshere in order to avoid to re-analyse the other mdwn files that were not edited. I don't care if a link is removed, or if there are duplicates because they can easily be uniqued. I just tried your dir solution which seems a bit complex to me and a second Make errors: https://github.com/kaihendry/backlinks/tree/dir-53800273

Comment: First solution is promising but there is no need to re-analyse every mdwn. Only the mdwn that changed needs be analysed on a second run.

Comment: Sorry, the second solution was working but only in the first invocation of make, which is not very useful. An `rm $<` was missing in the recipe that runs `backlinks.go`. Copies of the `mdwn` files were thus kept in the sub-directories and they were found by the `shell find` command during subsequent make runs. As the second (and first) solutions work only with a flat organization make was then failing. I fixed this.

Comment: Regarding this append issue, if we do not delete the `whatlinkshere` files and if a link is removed from a `mdwn` file, the back link reference will be kept in the `whatlinkshere` files. And it will be kept too in the generated HTML files. Is it OK for you? I mean, having wrong back links references that don't really exist?

Comment: In case the answer is yes, I added a third option that should do what you want.

Comment: I'm OK if there is a wrong back link. If it really bothers me, I'll go make clean and do a full rebuild. Eager to hear of the third option. Hopefully it's simpler than doing dirs! Thank you again,

Comment: Hi Renaud, did you want to make more changes to your answer in the new year?

Comment: No, not really, unless the third option I added is not what you asked for?